# tomahawk test tool installation

Tags: operating-system, centos

Can somebody shed some light on installing tomahawk pcap replay tool on centos ?

I did follow some instructions from the following site though it was on debian.
https://blog.packet-foo.com/2013/09/installing-tomahawk-ips-test-tool-on-debian-7/

Looked like tomhawk was installed . But i donot see all the required options from man page below :

http://tomahawk.sourceforge.net/MAN.html

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested on Centos yet. This is the script I have used to install Tomahawk on Ubuntu Server 14.04 (**32bits**). You can download the script from here: [Install Tomahawk test tool](http://fixbugs.tumblr.com/post/134273627341/install-tomahawk-test-tool)